# Root file system requires manual fsck

Tags: boot, initramfs, busybox

Whenever I switch on Ubuntu I always see the following message.

```
(Initramfs): /dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
  Inodes that were a part of a corrupted orphan linked lost found.
  /dev/sda1 : UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck manually.(I.e .,
  without -a or -p options). fsck exited with status code 4. The root
  filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
```

Comment: This shouldn't occur repeatedly. What do you to shut down Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, do you have a driver installed in Windows that allows it to read/view Ubuntu EXT4 files/partitions? Please start comments directed at me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: No i did not dual-boot windows @heynnema

Comment: I don't know but the message occurs repeatedly whenever I shutdown and then restart it again. @David Foerster

Comment: @AbhishekBarman: Again, how *exactly* do you shut down Ubuntu?

Comment: from the shutdown options.But my Ubuntu is getting hanging. every time I open. @David Foerster

Comment: Ah, so the system *hangs during shutdown*. Does it hang when you shutdown via `sudo shutdown`? If yes, what about `sudo reboot`?

Comment: @heynnema Hi, I have a similar problem, quite often I get my Ubuntu staled and when I restart I get a fail and a message to "RUN fsck MANUALLY". My system is dual-boot Windows10 and Ubuntu. Do Windows have anything to do with this? Please have in mind that I haven't been starting Windows for months.

Comment: @Danijel Windows should have nothing to do with Linux file system corruption (unless you've installed a Windows driver to read ext2/3/4 file systems). Have you run the `fsck` as per my answer? You should run `fsck` after every crash/hang.

Comment: OK. I did run `fsck`, and it fixed the problem. But constantly running `fsck` every few weeks doesn't seem to be the solution.

Answer (score 218):

From there, you should be able to drop to some maintenance shell (if not already opened), where you may run `fsck -yf /dev/sda1`.

If there are any errors rerun `fsck -yf /dev/sda1`

To login as usual simply run `exit` and proceed normally.

Comment: Here `y` in `-yf` is for `yes` wherever the system asks for `y/n` choice

Comment: I'm very grateful to mathguy for his comment, because remotely supporting someone who is using Linux for development but isn't intimately familiar with grub or working in the CLI makes complicated boot sequences almost impossible, but your comment and his mention that it should work at `initramfs` was invaluable. https://askubuntu.com/questions/885062/root-file-system-requires-manual-fsck/885066#comment1657117_885085

Comment: What does the -f mean? It's not documented on Debian 10 (neither is -y, explained by Rahul above).

Comment: The -f is to force check a filesystem, even if it is seen as clean. More of a reflex, might not be required when your system refuses to boot on that partition.

Comment: wow. Amazing!!!

Comment: Thanks this saved my installation. It wasn't booting and it wasn't showing my home folder.

Comment: lifesaver! Was able to fix the error and reboot.

Comment: Replace `sda1` with the `sda` with issue

Comment: Thanks (+1), this made my system (22.04) starting again. No clue why it happened, I did a normal reboot by GUI. Before that I already had some weird read-only-errors, that was why I rebooted, but then this error showed up and I had only a busybox console where I could fix it with fsck on /dev/sdc1 :)

Comment: Um... why does my screen now look like The Matrix?

Answer (score 43):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Recovery mode</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Root access</kbd>
- at the `#` prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer... (or if the above steps don't work for you)...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Why not just do the `fsck -fy /dev/sda1` directly on the prompt  ?

Comment: @SorenA at which prompt? I'm doing it at the root shell prompt, or in terminal with sudo. The file system isn't mounted there, and the fsck will run.

Comment: At the prompt he gets just after the message. I have never seen this message without a following 'minimal grub' prompt.

Comment: @SorenA fsck is not a grub command.

Comment: Belive me, it works !!

Comment: @SorenA at the grub prompt, grub rescue prompt, or the Initramfs prompt?

Comment: At the prompt he gets below the error message .. whatever it is.

Comment: "/bin/sh: sudo: not found" What should I do?

Comment: @Smile exactly what command did you type?

Comment: I went back to the last kernel version that was working fine. Maybe next time I'll use the newest kernel when it is working with no issue.

Comment: OK, it's more than a year later... Seeing the same problem as the OP reported, on one of my older machines (trying to start it up again after not using it for almost a year). Ubuntu 16.04 on it, dual boot with Windows 10. Windows starts OK; when trying to start Ubuntu (from GRUB menu) I get the same error at the OP. I found your answer here. Here's the issue: Once I select Advanced Options > Recovery Mode, there is no ROOT prompt. The system starts a check automatically, it finds problems with the root filesystem, and it gives a (initramfs) prompt, which does not recognize "sudo".

Comment: ... At the `(initramfs)` prompt I was able to run `fsck` directly (no need for `sudo`). The system fixed a whole bunch of filesystem errors, and I was able to restart Ubuntu normally. Your answer was almost correct.

Comment: @SorenA it worked for me like magic !

Comment: I do not see how it can work and indeed it does not work for me: `sudo fsck -f /` fails because `/` is mounted, and naturally I cannot unmount it because the partition is busy. There must be some missing step, like getting into `initramfs` etc.

Comment: @xealits Please use the second part of my answer, which now applies to all systems 18.04 and newer.

Comment: I would like to thanks, this solution resolve my ubuntu 1804 VM error issues...i just used sudo fsck -f /....it worked!

Comment: fsck -yf /dev/sda2 gives another error end kernal panic not syncing fatal exception in interrupt

Comment: @YogeshKushwaha Please start a new question, and give as much detail as you can.

Comment: @heynnema, thumbs up for a very very very useful answer!