# Doing disk checks on mounted OS partition?

Tags: disk, fsck, disk-check

I have problems with the main OS partition, but seems that i can't run fsck on mounted partitions?

Is there a way to diagnose mounted partition (i'm having problems lately) and if there isn't what is the best way to check it when not mounted?

Comment: It is best to run fsck from a live USB / CD

Comment: Perhaps reviewing [https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk/59077#59077](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59064/how-to-run-a-checkdisk/59077#59077) would help

Comment: I can suggest checking your Linux file system from initramfs or before your partitions are mounted that way you don't have to load a live cd/usb but using your own installation. I don't know the commands and I don't know if fsck is on there when the OS isn't load, in any case always have a handy bootable removable media with all your tools.

Comment: Please see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/885062/root-file-system-requires-manual-fsck/885085#885085 and please remember to vote if it was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a `fsck` on your root partition during the next reboot by creating a file named `forcefsck` in your root directory:

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
reboot
```

Comment: Will this work when I have encrypted hdd, home and swap?

Comment: It should work, I think, but I can't test it here. In the worst case, if that file prevented your installation from booting and failed to trigger a `fsck`, you could mount the partition from a live system and remove it from there. But as you'd have to do the `fsck` from a live system anyway if it doesn't work this way, I don't see a real problem with just trying this method.

Comment: will the file go away after running fsck or do I have to remove it manually afterwards?

Comment: @wotter It will get removed automatically during the file system check.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running it in "Initramfs".

`dracut` is a low-level tool for generating an "initramfs" images with a lot of capabilities.

Let's install it:

```
sudo apt install dracut
```

After installation is finished a new "initramfs" will be generated and GRUB will be updated automatically; It also removes `initramfs-tools`.

Now reboot the system, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make the GRUB appear (if it won't by itself), press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the default menu. There is a line which starts with `linux` at the end of that line add `rd.break=pre-mount` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to continue boot process.

it means that drop me into initramfs before mounting the filesystem, Now we are in a `sh` shell and we can simply run `fsck`:

```
$ fsch /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: clean,  xxx/xxx files,  yyy/yyy blocks
```

---

[dracut](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/dracut.8.html)
[dracut.cmdline](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html)