# Error: attempt to read or write outside hd0 Error: you need to load the kernel first

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10. After a force reboot of Windows 10 I get the errors shown in the picture.

Is there any possible solution using the grub command line? I don't have another pc so I can't make a live CD. I have an ssd and hdd

[image: photo of screen - attempt to write outside disk]

Trying rescue mode I get the same errors:

[image: error - you need to load the kernel first]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root file system requires manual fsck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885062/root-file-system-requires-manual-fsck)

Comment: I cannot boot recovery menu. The only way tl have terminal is by presing c in grub menu. Is it possible to run fsck from there?

Comment: You don't see `Advanced Options` in the grub menu?

Comment: Of course i see them but then if i select recovery mode i get the same errors + loading initial ramdisk

Comment: Ok press enter then post the image!

Comment: Ok.i posted it.

Comment: Try this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/397485/what-to-do-when-i-get-an-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-error

Comment: Tried that.but still i cannot boot linux so that i can run the last commands of solutions.when trying to boot linux i get the same error

Comment: Guys i have ubuntu installation iso on hdd. Is there a way to  boot live cd from there?through grub command line for example ?

Comment: [yes, there is a way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines) to boot an iso from a HDD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I boot an ISO file from my drive using grub2 on UEFI machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines)