# Boot installation iso from another hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I need to do fsck. But i am not able yo access ssd where ubuntu is installed and i have not second pc to make a usb with instsllation iso. Although i have the instsllation iso in my hdd.(look at image) is it possible to load it and run it from there so.i can fix my problem.The cause of the prohlem is at this post :[Error attempt to read or write outside hd0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090779/error-attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-hd0?noredirect=1#comment1795047_1090779)
[image]

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/ may help you get it up and running

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as i can see fr.your link he have access to linux. The only acces i have is grub command line

Comment: ah, ok, my bad, in that case here is grub-console only approach with commands listed in specific order (and what they actually do):
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293

Comment: What can i say for you man. Thanks a lot you are the best