# How can I undo a "read only file system" to make its directories valid?

Tags: lubuntu, mountpoint

## 19 March 2019 introduction

My computer has 2 drives, I use the 2nd for file storage and the 1st for the OS. Been unable to access the 2nd's contents. I get the following message clicking on it:

```
Error creating mount point `/media/jay/HP_PAVILION Adjacent Reserve 1_2': Read-only file system
```

I read the 2011 suggestion Lekensteyn made at [How to make read-only file system writable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable) and tried the following command on LXTerminal:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/jay/HP_PAVILION Adjacent Reserve 1_2'
```

I got the following response:

```
[sudo] password for jay: 
mount: /media/jay/HP_PAVILION Adjacent Reserve 1_2: mount point does not exist.
```

When I try to access the shortcuts I made to folders that were on the drive, I get messages like:

> The specified directory '/media/jay/HP_PAVILION Adjacent Reserve
>   1_2/!uTorrent completed downloads' is not valid

This is also giving me an 'error' when trying to magnet-torrent (via Transmission) the latest (18.10) version of Lubuntu which I'd like to try out.

Even downloading it normally gives an error:

> could not be saved, because the disk, folder, or file is write-protected.
>   Write-enable the disk and try again, or try saving in a different location.

My comp also in past has spontaneously blackscreened (audio kept going) after around 20 minutes of running.

This may be related to past problems of blackscreenining on boot-up unless I do a "Resume Normal Boot" after AORMing (Advanced Options : Recover Mode) on startup.

I asked about this back in September [How do I fix a frozen black screen on Lubuntu startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077616/how-do-i-fix-a-frozen-black-screen-on-lubuntu-startup)

However I get so frustrated by it that I abandon the comp for months when the problems seem to accrue... I'd really like to be able to understand why it black-screened and if this is connected to why my 2nd drive was put into write-protect, and if it's connected to the black screen on startup.

Would I be better served trying out another Ubuntu OS? I don't know which is compatible with really old graphics hardware.

---

### reply 1 to guiverc:

I read a February 2017 reply by nnema at [Root file system requires manual fsck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885062/root-file-system-requires-manual-fsck)

This appears to imply that I would do a reboot, and then when I do an AORM as I usually do, instead of cancelling the Advanced Options Recovery Mode that I should select "root access" and then enter one of the following lines:

```
sudo fsck -f /
sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1
```

Any commendations which would be better? Either way I must type 'reboot' after.

Soren A asked why not try using the terminal, so I tried this with the 1st and got following readout. I typed "y" whenever it asked "fix?" because that seemed like the right thing to do...

```
jay@KingdomClubs:~$ sudo fsck -f
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 4851502 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 5115118 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 14942419 passes checks, but checksum does not match inode.  Fix<y>? yes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(60070928--60070931)
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1833 (29950, counted=29954).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong (73653422, counted=73666086).
Fix<y>? yes
Inode bitmap differences:  -4851502 -5115118
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #592 (4797, counted=4798).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #624 (3270, counted=3271).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong (19246314, counted=19246209).
Fix ('a' enables 'yes' to all) <y>? yes

/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: ***** REBOOT SYSTEM *****
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: 234367/19480576 files (1.5% non-contiguous), 4224474/77890560 blocks
```

I assume since it says "reboot system" that I should do a restart now. I will try this now and if I can still use my computer, update with whether or not the drive is accessible.

---

### reply 2 to Nonny Moose:

looked up [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 18.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) which recommends getting "Disks Utility" to do this. I did not see it under "System Tools" so AFAIK it doesn't come with Lubuntu by default.

I opened Synaptic Package Manager to try and install it and as soon as I entered my admin password I got the following error message:

```
An error occurred
The following details are provided.

E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease - mkstemp (30: Read-only file system)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Do you know if there is any default software that comes with Lubuntu that I could use to check SMART status? I don't think I will be able to install anything new until I fix this.

---

### update 3 (March 20) FSCK fixed it, thanks guys!

Comment: The mount error is telling you `/media/jay/HP_PAVILION Adjacent Reserve 1_2` does not exist; it must already exist (as a directory) in order for you to mount a device to it.  A common reason for a file-system to be read-only is because it has errors, and needs `fsck` (file system check)

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that the file system to which the 2nd drive is mounted (i.e. your OS drive) is read-only. You might want to run a SMART check.

Comment: Thanks you two for the fast replies! I have edited in responses above to your comments. I am doing a reboot now to see if the fsck fixes accompished access to the Synaptic Package Manager so I can install the Disks Utility which NM recommended.

Comment: okay I rebooted and can access my drive now, fsck suggestions seem to have worked