# Booting gets stuck on a black screen with some text

Tags: boot, grub2, 19.04

I have Ubuntu 19.04 dual booted alongside Windows 10. I had not used my PC for a month. The last time I used my PC, Ubuntu was working great. Today (after a month), when I turned on my PC, the boot process got stuck on a black screen with some text written on it.
I don't understand what is written (too much technical terms). And at last line "intramfs" is written and I can type and enter any command into it (just like in the terminal).

[image: black screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can find the solution in this part of the error:

```
/dev/sda10: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda10 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.227.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu7) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) _
```

so i did some digging for you and your question is already answered:

same problem as yours dual boot with windows os

[fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

[Root file system requires manual fsck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885062/root-file-system-requires-manual-fsck)

if that wasnt helpful search 
`UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY`
there is a lot of discussion about it

because of low reputation i couldnt flag the question or comment below it so sorry

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to try to fix the error:

```
sudo fsck -fy /dev/sda10
```